# Updating the local database from a remote database

Tags: database, oracle

I have a local database used for development and testing purpose and one remote database in the live environment. Both are in Oracle. The local database contains the same table structure and all with old data. I need to update the local database with the data from the remote database. (I tried exp/imp. But it is showing an error like `Object already exists`). Can anyone please help me to figure out what may be the problem or what is the best method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to drop your local tables first.  exp/imp does not remove existing tables or data before importing, if I recall.

Comment: Should I drop the schema and recreate it or should I drop only the tables?